# how to tunnel to another computer using a middle computer? SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port, tunnel

I am in my local computer, and i just want to test reverse ssh so that i access computer 2 and access computer 3 through computer 2 and make computer 3 respond to me in lets say i want to access postgresql on computer 3.

how to do that with ssh and using ports? 5432 is the port of sql

my approach is this:

```
ssh -L 3000:localhost:5432 <ipaddressof the 2nd computer>
```

so im inside 2nd computer now.

in the terminal again i type:

```
ssh -L 3000:localhost:5432 <ipaddress of the 3rd computer>
```

and im inside the 3rd computer now. And i dont know what to do anymore, how to access its sql?

i tried this code which doesn't work:

```
psql -U myusername -p 3000
```

Comment: This is about configuring and using existing software. SO is really for questions about how to write software. Might work on superuser or possibly ServerFault (but I don't use either enough to be sure).

Comment: this just include ssh in linux terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ssh -L localhost:3000:<ip address 3rd computer>:5432 <ip address 2nd computer>
```

And then:

```
psql -U myusername -h localhost -p 3000
```

This works if:

1. The 2nd computer has access to the 3rd computer
2. The sshd config on the 2nd computer allows TCP forwarding (default is yes)

Comment: Hi sir, can you explain your ssh code above sir? im quite confused. And i tried it it still gives error, saying `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.3000"?` so can you explain your code so i can modify it to my own? thanks

Comment: The -L option says "forward local connections made to localhost:3000 to the address <3rd computer>:5432 on the remote side". The local connection will be accepted by the ssh process, then forwarded to the sshd on the 2nd computer, which will then make an outgoing connection to the 3rd computer. To debug this, first get into the 3rd computer and see if you can do "psql -U myusername -p 5432" there. Make sure the a postgres instance is running. Then get into the 2nd computer and make sure you can do "psql -U myusername -h <3rd computer> -p 5432". Report back here.

Comment: in your code how does the second computer redirects the data from 3rd computer to mine?

Comment: As I said, the local connection will be accepted by the ssh process, then forwarded to the sshd on the 2nd computer, which will then make an outgoing connection to the 3rd computer. Not sure what the confusion is. Once the connections are made, the ssh/sshd processes forward data back and forth.

Comment: my understanding is this based on your code: when i send command using my `localhost:3000` it sends it to 3rd computer on its port 5432 and thats the end of it, i dont understand anymore what's the use of the 2nd computer address in the last part. please bear with me here. thanks sir

Comment: I am sorry I am not quite understanding your issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30875/discussion-between-ziffusion-and-ruggedbuteducated)

Comment: hi, i replied to your chat. please check it. thanks